# CSS: make element look pale but not transparent

Tags: css

Bootstrap uses `opacity: 0.65` on disabled buttons, but this makes the element translucent. I don't want the user to see through a disabled element, so is there any other to achieve a similar pale colour look?

I have tried other [CSS3 filters](https://developer.mozilla.org/en/docs/Web/CSS/filter), but none of them (apart from `opacity`) generates a pleasant and clear effect to indicate disabled.

Edit:

I decided to hack this by wrapping the buttons in `span`s with a white background. But I am curious if there's something as simple as the one-liner `opacity` style.

Comment: You're going to have to be a little more specific. Is a 'desaturated' effect to indicate that a button is disabled what you're going for? Could you provide some code or a JS fiddle of the button you have already?

Comment: PrtScreen, color pick, apply.

Comment: as powerbuoy suggest you just have to style it - pick color for text, border and background and set opacity to 1.

Comment: @styke Desaturate has no effect on black-on-white though (`btn-default`). @powerbuoy: To do this manually requires overriding foreground and background colour for quite a number of styles. I am not sure it's very practical.

Answer (score 0):

If you use [hsla()](https://css-tricks.com/yay-for-hsla/) colors in your css you can adjust the saturation or lightness of the color in a convenient way, in your case you might want to desaturate the color or adjust it so it become less contrasting to the text/background its located at.

You can explore the [HSL paramerters here](https://css-tricks.com/examples/HSLaExplorer/)